# Serilog and IoC unity

Tags: frameworks, inversion-of-control, serilog

I'm trying to implement Serilog into my project but can't seem to get it working
I have this class where i call ILogger in the constructor but also tried to do a manual resolve in there.

```
private readonly ILogger logger;
private ILogger logger1;
    

    public EstoxController(ILogger logger1)
    {
        this.logger = IoC.Container.Resolve<ILogger>();
        this.logger1 = logger1;
    }
```

And then i call it in a method that needs logging in the same class

```
   public virtual ActionResult GetEstoxQueryUrl(string id, EstoxEnvironmentType environmentType)
    {
        var logger3 = IoC.Container.Resolve<ILogger>();

        logger.Information("test");
        logger1.Information("test");
        logger3.Information("testing3");
```

And in my container configuration i have as followed.

```
  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.File("logtesting.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
        .CreateLogger();
        IoC.Container.RegisterInstance(Log.Logger);
```

I just can't seem to get it working please help

Comment: Can you update your code example to show how you are using Unity to resolve your objects? Constructor injection is only going to take place if you are doing `IoC.Container.Resolve<EstoxController>()` somewhere. You also failed to mention which of your examples (`logger`, `logger1`, `logger3`, etc) are not working. "I just can't seem to get it working please help" is a severe lack of detail.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to specify the service when registering:

```
IoC.Container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(Log.Logger);
```